# Postresql remove single table via shell script

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I have a config script that resets my development PostgreSQL database. This is written as a shell script. However, I would like to keep one table that does not have any foreign keys anywhere else. Therefore I am looking for a way to delete single tables rather than the whole database.

This is my current setup, which works perfectly. It drops the database, creates new and creates all the tables for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PGPASSWORD=$1

echo "Configuring ..."

dropdb -U $2 $3
createdb -U $2 $3

psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/user.sql
psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/account.sql
psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/account-user.sql
psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/fuelprice.sql
psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/vehicle.sql
psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/account-vehicle.sql

echo "All configured."
```

However, I would like to be able to instead of dropping the database and create new one just delete certain tables and re-create those.

I have tried following:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PGPASSWORD=$1

echo "Configuring ..."

psql -U $2 $3 -c `DROP TABLE "Config.User"`

psql -U $2 $3 < ./bin/sql/user.sql


echo "All configured."
```

The part that I can not make work is:
psql -U $2 $3 -c `DROP TABLE "Config.User"`

I am getting following reply from the command line:
psql: option requires an argument -- c

I had a look on the help but I am unsure what additional argument I might be missing.

Please note that $1 is password variable, $2 is user and $3 is database.

Comment: Use single quotes, not backticks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from user 'melpomene'. All that was needed is to swap ` for '.